# Specific wifi doesn't show up after password change windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I've changed the password of my wifi and now it doesn't show up anymore on my window 8.1 pc.
I can connect and use it from 2 android devices and a windows 7 laptop.

I think there is an issue with the profile stored on my pc but I'm really not good on Window 8.1

How can I get my wifi network to show up ?

Here is my ipconfig :

[image]

I'm connected through Android tethering for internet access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but changing the channel from 13 to 1 did the trick ! 
I tried multiple times, on 13-12 he deasappers from the wifi on my Windows 8.1 pc (but still visible on other devices) and as soon as I choose chanel 1, my pc can see it !

There is only one other Wifi in my range, and its using channel 6, so I can't understand what is the problem (channel 13 was selected automatically by the default settings).

Anyway, thanks Peter, you show me the path !

Comment: That's pretty exotic. Did you purchase your WiFi access point in Switzerland and your PC in the US/Canada? see the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_concerns

Comment: Both pc and wifi access point was purchased in the same store (which is a specialized store for informatic)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the old entry for the WiFi first (Charms->Settings->Change PC Settings->Network->Connections->Manage known networks->Chose a network to forget).

If it doesn't work after that, make sure you are in range and didn't choose a band/protocol on the access point that's not supported by your PC. 2.4 GHz b/g should be supported by all of them, 2.4 GHz n by most, and 5.0 GHz n/ac is supported by some. I usually use both 2.4 GHz n and 5 GHz n/ac with 2 separate SSIDs, because all my devices support at least 2.4GHz n. If you don't understand what this is about and you didn't change your router's default settings, this is already set up correctly.

Comment: I already did remove the WIFI from the known network I have even removed the profile with netsh command. I'll try to check the band I used, but I did not change the default value so I don't think the problem come from that. The signal strength is seen as excellent by my phone when I am next to my PC. Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: My Router is set up as 802.11 b/g/n, and I can't find how to change it to b/g...